# How would one go about creating Fronts that don't fall under the listed dangers, etc.?

Tags: dungeon-world, gm-preparation

How would I go about creating a front that doesn't use one of the listed dangers? Would I have to find something similar but not quite correct? Create a new one? If I create a new one, how would I do so? Does anyone have experience doing so, and if so how did you go about it?

Comment: Did you have a particular kind of Front you wanted to make, but couldn't? I've taken a quick look at the rules for Front creation, and it seems to have the major bases covered.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can write your own dangers. The typology in the book is there to help you do it quickly.

The important thing isn't the type you assign to a danger, it's the *impulse* and *moves* it has.

The existing types help streamline this process: if you have a popular fantasy trope in mind, they'll explain how to make it active, through what it seeks — that's the impulse — and how it acts — that's the GM moves.

The pre-written dangers cover a range of tropes, so there's often a danger that fits perfectly except for the description itself. E.g. when the necro-alchemist creates a sentient black oil that turns people into living zombies, it isn't really a "shadowland" or a "corrupted place," but I can crib most of the "shadowland" stuff and put this in my notes, likes this:

> The Black Oil
>
> impulse: to corrupt or consume the living
>
> moves: corrupt a natural law, spread to an adjacent place, hide something from sight, leave a lingering effect, offer power, vomit forth a lesser monster (oil zombies!!)

If you've got a very clear picture in mind that doesn't really match anything provided, feel free to just write it up as a totally custom danger. I promise you it won't harm the game.

Comment: Playing Apocalypse World, I always use the pre-defined threat types because I've got [analysis like this](http://apocalypse-world.com/forums/index.php?topic=7479.0) to help me make the most of them. I haven't found something similarly expansive for Dungeon World yet, though.

Comment: Oh, that Black Oil. I need to invite another adventuring party to Hochen. (That's a great write up of it though)